# axis2 client logging request response spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, soap, apache-axis

How can we Log **Axis2 SOAP request and response** that are called from Spring boot service classes. Spring logback looging is not logging client request and response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if calling from Spring changes anything but you can add hadlers to your axis2 client. Axis2 processes messages in phases. You can get all those phases and add your custom handler to any phase you want. Such handler can do everything with message, including logging whole content or modyfing it.

```
// get AxisConfiguration from client
AxisConfiguration axisConf = stub._getServiceClient().getAxisConfiguration();

// create your custom phase
Phase phase = new Phase(OUT_LOGGER);

// add your custom handler to your custom phase
phase.addHandler(new MessageContentLoggerHandler());

// get all phases processed when message is sent away 
// and add your custom phase
axisConf.getOutFlowPhases().add(phase);

// get all phases for incoming messages 
//and add handler to Security phase 
// (that's where security headers are added to SOAP message)
List<Phase> phasesIn = axisConf.getInFlowPhases();
addHandlerToSecurity(phasesIn);

// similar to above but now these are phases processed 
// when there is fault in incoming communication
List<Phase> phasesInFault = axisConf.getInFaultFlowPhases();
phasesInFault.add(0, phase);
addHandlerToSecurity(phasesInFault);
```

Adding to Security phase:

```
public void addHandlerToSecurity(List<Phase> phases) {
        try {
            for (Phase p : phases) {
                if ("Security".equals(p.getName())) {
                    p.addHandler(new MessageContentLoggerHandler());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

Your custom handler has to implement invoke(MessageContext msgContext) method. MessageContent contains whole SOAP envelope i.e. your requests and responses from web service.

```
public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
        String envelope = msgContext.getEnvelope().toString();
        // do something with content of SOAP envelope
        return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
}
```